# Proper way to handle input disable? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and want to make a simple form:
with two buttons:

```
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

I want to disable these 2 buttons accordingly to the text input: if the input is empty, buttons should be disabled.
What's the best way to do so?

1) Check text value on render:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={(this.state.value == "" ? true : false )} />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick={this.handleReset} disabled={(this.state.value == "" ? true : false )}/>
```

2) Having an internal state, and updating it on every interaction with the text input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={ this.state.formDisabled } />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick={this.handleReset} disabled={ this.state.formDisabled } />
```

Comment: I personally think your first option is the best. You could even write `disabled={this.state.value === ""}`

Comment: I also thought this was better because you don't add and handle another state that simply converts a variable that you already have into a boolean. Right? @Tholle

Comment: I guess option 1 is good enough, option 2 is valid as well, but I will use it if formDisabled will be used to enable/disable a different functionality

Comment: @LucaRossi I agree with that. It might be a good idea to have additional state if you e.g. only want to show the error when the user clicks the submit button, but having additional state for just `this.state.value === ""` doesn't feel necessary.

Comment: If the form grows to have more inputs then calling a function to determine if the button is disabled makes sense. But since your logic is so simple a quick inline equality check is fine.

Comment: I'd also vote for the first option. If the requirement is simple, stay simple. You will refactor this when you'll need something more complex, but right now, staying close to the value is simple, readable and efficient.

Comment: Now the situation is much clearer. Thank you all, really!!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!this.state.value} />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick={this.handleReset} disabled{!this.state.value}/>
```